# Qml Qt Quick Control 2: Font size difference between Text and ComboBox

Tags: windows, qt, qml, qtquick2

Let's look at this very simple sample application, built with QT 5.9 on a Windows 10:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {



        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 20
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 20

        Text {
            id: text
            text: "This is a sample Text"
        }
        ComboBox {
            model: [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        }

        Text {
            text: "Another Text"
        }
        TextField {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            text: "User Input"
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it without any further modifications from the QT Creator, I get a very weird relationship between the Font-Size of the `Text` and the `ComboBox` and `TextField` blocks. It looks like this:
[image: Small Text]

The text is too small, and the ComboBoxes (and their Fonts) are HUGE.

If I change the main function to set the default font size explicitely to the system font size using this code (It's the same when I hardcode the `setPointSizeF` to 12, which is the supposed standard size on windows):

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

auto font = app.font();
QFontInfo fi(font.defaultFamily());
font.setPointSizeF(fi.pointSizeF());
app.setFont(font);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

It looks like this:
[image: Huge Text]

Now the "Relative Dimensions" are more balanced, but overall everything is just "too big". Additionally, if I'm opening the ComboBox, I get again very small text:
[image: Wrong ComboBox]

Did I miss to set some default here? How can I achieve a more balanced look that fit's better into the Operating Systems' native font sizes?

Answer (score 1):

The combobox delegates use a different font to the application default.

Delegate font can be changed to match the rest of the application as follows:

```
ComboBox {
    id: control

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        width: control.width
        text: control.textRole ? (Array.isArray(control.model) ? modelData[control.textRole] : model[control.textRole]) : modelData
        font.weight: control.currentIndex === index ? Font.DemiBold : Font.Normal
        font.family: control.font.family
        font.pointSize: control.font.pointSize
        highlighted: control.highlightedIndex === index
        hoverEnabled: control.hoverEnabled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the font sizes as defaults and instead set the widths of your items. You could explicitly set the `width` of the ComboBox and TextField, or if you want to use the ColumnLayout to have consistent sizing of all the items, see example below,

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 20
        width: text.width

        Text {
            id: text
            text: "This is a sample Text"
        }
        ComboBox {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            model: [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        }

        Text {
            text: "Another Text"
        }
        TextField {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "User Input"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. In my code, there is a mismatch between the font sizes of `Text` (very small) and `ComboBox` (big) - your code doesn't change that.
Maybe my screenshots were a bit unclear. I updated the question with a newer Screenshot (Actually, your code is running) and rephrased it a bit. I don't actually understand why ComboBox uses 12pt as Font-Size whereas Text uses 8.

Comment: yes, I misunderstood. I have run the code from your question using Qt 5.9 on Win 7 and Ubuntu, and the font sizes of the 3 Item types are all identical, which means I will be unable to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try setting: `font.pointSize: 12` in both the combobox and text fields. This works for me on Qt 5.9 in Windows 10. I am still trying to figure how to change the font size inside the combobox drop down; will expand this answer when I know.

Comment: You can do this like this:    popup.font.pointSize: 12